# label value assigned to a block which is not a set ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

When, I make a rule like this ,

```
/* date type */
date: 'date' '(' value = STRING ')' ;
/* field["value"] */
key: name = ID '[' value = STRING ']';
whereExpr: key op =('>'|'<'|'>='|'<='|'=') value = (STRING | ID | INTEGER | DOUBLE | date ) ;
```

in my grammar,ANTLR displays the following error.

```
error(130): WhereParser.g4:14:43: label value assigned to a block which is not a set
1 error(s)
```

Why ?.
How I can fix that ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only assign labels to a set of tokens, not parser rules. In other words, `value = (STRING | ID | INTEGER | DOUBLE | date)` is invalid because `date` is a parser rule. Fix it by removing the `value =` label:

```
whereExpr
 : key op=('>'|'<'|'>='|'<='|'=') (STRING | ID | INTEGER | DOUBLE | date)
 ;
```